# I was not able to import libraries in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

what that mean when i get the below error in google colab ?
File "", line 1

coding pyton in google colab and i was imorting  the libraries
and it give me this error

Comment: You have to actually show us the error...

Comment: ...you should also provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem, and include as detailed a description as possible of what your environment looks like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely you need to install the libraries before importing them. You can do this by using a different code cell. An example below for selenium:

```
!pip install selenium
```

Use this line and replace selenium with the library you need and run the code-cell.
After this the code should run without errors.

Answer (score -1):

Fist of all, you need to show the Error you got.
But maybe you haven't installed the Packages, that's why you got error while Importing.

So you need to install the Packages using " pip install "